# How to use a dynamic image from Firebase as background image?

Tags: css, firebase, polymer-1.0

I'm storing user profile information in Firebase, which includes a link to an image of the user. I would like to use this image as a background image in a Material Design Card populated using the Polymer firebase-collection element to retrieve the user profile information. I am able to retrieve the user profile image, but am not able to set the background image of the Card to the user's profile image by adding a style attribute on the element. Is it possible to use a dynamic image as a background image?

```
<dom-module id="my-element">
<template>
 <style>
 :host {
  display: block;
 }
 @media (max-width: 600px) {
   h1.paper-font-display1 {
     font-size: 24px;
   }
 }
 .demo-card-square.mdl-card {
   width: 280px;
   height: 320px;
 }
 .demo-card-square > .mdl-card__title {
   color: #000;
 }
 .circle-image {
   border-radius: 50%;
   width: 60%;
   height: 80%;
   margin: auto; 
   padding-top: 14px;
 }
 </style>

 <firebase-collection
  location="myFirebaseLocation"
  order-by-child="displayName"
  data="{{users}}">
 </firebase-collection>

 <template is="dom-repeat" items="[[users]]">
  <div class="demo-card-square mdl-card mdl-shadow--2dp">
   <div class="mdl-card__title mdl-card--expand" style="background:url([[item.0.imageUrl]]) center no-repeat #46B6AC">  <!-- This does not display the image -->
    <h2 class="mdl-card__title-text">[[item.0.displayName]]</h2>
    <img src="[[item.0.imageUrl]]" class="circle-image"</> <!-- This works -->
   </div>
   <div class="mdl-card__supporting-text">
    <span>[[item.0.occupation]]</span>
   </div>
   <div class="mdl-card__actions mdl-card--border">
    <a class="mdl-button mdl-button--colored mdl-js-button mdl-js-ripple-effect">
     View Profile
    </a>
   </div>
  </div>
 </template>
</template>

<script>
(function() {
  Polymer({
    is: 'my-element',

    properties: {
      users: {
        type: Array,
      }
    }
  }); 
})();
</script>
</dom-module>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a computed method to calculate the style

```
computeStyle : function(user) {
    return "background-image: url(" + user.imageUrl + ');';
}
```

Then call it from the template

```
style="computeStyle(item.0)"
```

Ideally you would create a separate element for the card and call it from the repeat setting the user

That will give you a bit of reuse and nice separation, single purpose, etc

You will also be able to give your containing element an ID, which would give you access to the style in a more granular way

```
this.$.myContainer.style.backgroundImage 
             = 'url(' + this.user.imageUrl + ')';
```

Comment: I used this syntax to get it working `style={{computeStyle(item.0.imageUrl)}}` to call the function in Polymer, but otherwise generating the style as a computed function worked.

Comment: cool, I was thinking computeStyle may do more than just the background url based on the user,  but makes no odds. :)